# Is there a way to emulate a DHCP server (overlay network)

Tags: dhcp, vlan, openvswitch

I have created an overlay Level 2 network using VLAN tags with `Open vSwitch`. I want a Level 3 one so I need to give each VM a consistent IP address.

I'd like every host on this VLAN to get an IP address from a DHCP server, so I can plug in and out every VM without having to manually set static IP addresses in each one of them.

I though about attach a DHCP-VM on this VLAN : this VM would contain a DHCP server implementation (`Ubuntu` default one is ok) and as the default DHCP is out of this VLAN, every VM attached would get the IP address from this VM's DHCP.

But I am introducing a whole VM, in other words another machine, just for a DHCP server, this solution seems just too much. Can you suggest me any other solution?

Comment: Install DHCP on an existing server?

Comment: If you're trying to get to a layer 3 network, you'll need some device that can route between the two networks. Almost any device that can route between the two networks can be setup to do forward DHCP requests.

Comment: `Is there a way to emulate a DHCP server` - Yes. Deploy a DHCP server. `But I am introducing a whole VM, in other words another machine, just for a DHCP server, this solution seems just too much` - How else would you deploy a DHCP server without deploying a DHCP server? If you don't want to deploy a dedicated VM for this then use one of the existing VM's.

Comment: Please do not post on multiple Stack Exchanges sites. Questions will be migrated if needed.  http://superuser.com/questions/727545/need-a-dhcp-server-solution-for-overlay-network

Comment: Just deleted sorry...I copied the question because it suited more to serverfault but totally forgot to delete it from super user

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, either you have a router on the network that does dhcp serving, or you can have a small (1 virt proc 512mb ram) linux box running dhcpd, but you need *something*. A small linux dhcpd would be an *extremely* small footprint on any decent sized hypervised box, imho.

Comment: Is there any particular small distro you would suggest me?

Comment: Well, I'm partial to CentOS minimal, it's pretty small and you always make it *smaller*, depending on what you require, which isn't much.